# How do I apply an 'advanced' query-based constraint?

Tags: postgresql

I can't find a way to apply an 'advanced' query-based constraint.

For example, with the following fictitious schema, how can I enforce that the total percentage of Bob's daily activities does not exceed 100%?

I've already looked into [trigger constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createconstraint.html) but I don't think they're going to do what I want (abort the INSERT/UPDATE if some criteria is met).

Thanks for reading my question and any help you can offer.

```
create table employee (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

create table work_day (
    employee_id integer references employee(id) NOT NULL,
    percentage integer NOT NULL CHECK (percentage > 0 and percentage <= 100),
    activity varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO employee (name) VALUES ('bob');

-- Bob spends 50% of the day slacking, 20% eating and 30% working (total = 100%)
INSERT INTO work_day (employee_id, percentage, activity) VALUES (1, 50, 'slacking'); 
INSERT INTO work_day (employee_id, percentage, activity) VALUES (1, 20, 'eating');
INSERT INTO work_day (employee_id, percentage, activity) VALUES (1, 30, 'working');

-- This should be invalid!!! 100% of Bob's time has already been allocated
INSERT INTO work_day (employee_id, percentage, activity) VALUES (1, 10, 'invalid');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pl/pgsql-based [constraint trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createconstraint.html) is what you want. sum() the thing, and check if it is within the defined bounds. If not, [raise an exception](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) and the statement will be cancelled.

Alternatively, have a normal trigger store/update the total activity in the employee table, and place a constraint on the latter.

Comment: Thanks Denis. I'll update the post when I have a working solution but this sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I've tested this code and it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_work_day_percentage() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF coalesce((select sum(percentage) 
                    from work_day
                    where employee_id = NEW.employee_id
                    and activity != NEW.activity), 0) 
                + coalesce(NEW.percentage, 0) > 100 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Employee % exceeds 100 percent', NEW.employee_id;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER work_day_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON work_day
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_work_day_percentage();
```

FYI, a table constraint won't do it: According to the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtable.html),

> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot
>   contain subqueries nor refer to
>   variables other than columns of the
>   current row.

Comment: Fail: `update work_day set percentage = 100 - percentage;` (use an after trigger to make it work).

Comment: I would just like to confirm that I have tested this approach and it works. Thanks again to everyone who helped.